# Django model where only one row can have active = True

Tags: python, django

I am creating theme settings for a project I'm working on. I want the user to be able to create multiple themes (rows in the database) but only have one theme active at a time.

```
class SingleActiveModel(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Save active = False to all other rows or alternative
        super(SingleActiveModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

class Theme(SingleActiveModel):
    some_setting = models.SomeField()
    active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Comment: Just have a model for Themes and put a FK in User (or some Settings model) representing the active theme. Trying to enforce this in the Theme model itself is bad design.

Comment: tzaman speak the truth :), with your implementation its working only for 1 user, tzaman solution is scalable.

Comment: It took me a second to dissect that FK meant ForeignKey. tzaman does speak the truth I was blind to miss this.

Answer (score 5):

First put the `active` field in your base class - it's the one that use it so it shouldn't depend on the child classes declaring it.

Then it's just a master of updating the other records `active` field value if necessary:

```
class SingleActiveModel(models.Model):
    active = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.active:
            # select all other active items
            qs = type(self).objects.filter(active=True)
            # except self (if self already exists)
            if self.pk:
                qs = qs.exclude(pk=self.pk)
            # and deactive them
            qs.update(active=False) 

        super(SingleActiveModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)


class Theme(SingleActiveModel):
    # the active field is inherited
    some_setting = models.SomeField()
```

Not that this won't solve the problem of "one active item *per user*", but then the solution is simpler, cf tzaman's comment:

> Just have a model for Themes and put a FK in User (or some Settings model) representing the active theme